# How to access a class file in web project to silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, service

I'm new to silverlight. I got a separate class file in web project and i have to access the class file in silverlight project xaml page. I have created a service and added the reference to silverlight project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you cannot access class direcly you need to expose it via service only.there is no other option.**

To access any class or data in you silverlight project you need to specify the contract in wcf servcie class. You class will be avaiale in silverlight application once you do as below.

[WCF Contracts](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/interview/exam286-what-are-contracts-in-wcf.aspx)

In WCF, all services expose contracts. The contract is a platform-neutral and standard way of describing what the service does.

Describe which operations the client can perform on the service.

There are two types of Service Contracts.

- ServiceContract - This attribute is used to define the Interface.
- OperationContract - This attribute is used to define the method inside Interface.

Example

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IMyContract
{
   [OperationContract]
   string MyMethod( );
}
class MyService : IMyContract
{
   public string MyMethod( )
   {
      return "Hello World";
   }
}
```

Data contracts

There are two types of Data Contracts.
 - DataContract - attribute used to define the class 
 - DataMember - attribute used to define the properties

Example

```
[DataContract]
class Contact
{
   [DataMember]
   public string FirstName;

   [DataMember]
   public string LastName;
}
```

Comment: This is a separate class file in web project and i have to access that class in silverlight project.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar - you cannot access it direcly you nee dto expose it via service only..there is no other option.

Comment: So i have to create a class within the service and can access in the silverlight project right?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar - yes , you need to expose the class using service that will do work for you...